# Formatar Data Angular

Tags: angular, data, formatação

Ola, Eu tenho a seguinte string:

```
Tue Oct 16 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)
```

E queria formatar ela em `dd/mm/yyyy` e meu objetivo e que fique `16/10/2018`

Como eu teria que fazer esse processo de formatação?

Answer (score 1):

Abaixo um exemplo de componente com imports para converter datas.

É importante **importar, colocar como provider e instanciar** para conseguir usar o DatePipe.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'; //import do datePipe

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component.css'],
    providers: [DatePipe] //DatePipe como provider
})
export class PesquisaMapaComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
            private datePipe: DatePipe //instanciar o DatePipe
    ) { }

    this.datePipe.transform(dataValor, 'dd/MM/yyyy') //um exemplo de uso. isso irá retornar sua data no formato selecionado, no caso 'dd/MM/yyyy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você está com uma versão recente (5.5 pra frente se não me engano), como exemplificado na [documentação de pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), você precisa usar pipes desta maneira:

```
<p>The hero's birthday is {{ birthday | date:"MM/dd/yy" }} </p>
```

No seu caso ficaria

```
<p> Data atual é {{ data | date:"dd/MM/yyyy" }} </p>
```

Comment: Porem eu quero essa formatação para fazer consultas no banco, nao para imprimir no html.

Comment: bom, pra isso você precisa verificar qual o tipo do valor que você está querendo modificar, é um `Date`? você quer pegar uma data já informada ou quer a data atual com o comando `new Date().toLocaleString()`?

Comment: A data esta armazenada em uma variavel agora, uma variavel do tipo any que provavelmente esta sendo impressa em string

Comment: armazena esta variável numa outra do tipo `Date` e tenta dar um console nela assim: `console.log(variavel..getFullYear())`. Dá erro ou trás 2018?